# Array of Json values to Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Json array which has key value pairs like below.

```
[
    [
        {
            "value": "Dimension1",
            "formattedValue": "Dimension1"
        },      
        {
            "value": "Amount1",
            "formattedValue": "Amount1"
        },      
        {
            "value": "17253512.430000003",
            "formattedValue": "17,253,512.43"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "value": "Dimension1",
            "formattedValue": "Dimension1"
        },      
        {
            "value": "Amount2",
            "formattedValue": "Amount2"
        },      
        {
            "value": "-143721131.88999993",
            "formattedValue": "-143,721,131.89"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "value": "Dimension1",
            "formattedValue": "Dimension1"
        },      
        {
            "value": "Amount3",
            "formattedValue": "Amount3"
        },      
        {
            "value": "160974644.31999999",
            "formattedValue": "160,974,644.32"
        }
    ]   
]
```

I wanted to convert this into dataframe output like below. How can I achieve this please?

| Dimension | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dimension1 | 17,253,512.43 | -143,721,131.89 | 160,974,644.32 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are interested in 'formattedValue' so try:

```
df=(pd.DataFrame(data).stack()
      .map(lambda x:x.get('formattedValue'))
      .unstack().pivot(0,1,2)
      .rename_axis(columns=None,index='Dimension').reset_index())
```

**Note:** here data variable is your json data

output of df:

```
    Dimension   Amount1         Amount2             Amount3
0   Dimension1  17,253,512.43   -143,721,131.89     160,974,644.32
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked as expected for my Json

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd  


data = 'your_json.json'
with open(data) as trainer:
    trainee= json.load(trainer)
df = pd.json_normalize(data['results'])
```